# Show that the subspace $U$ is $\phi^z$-invariant

Tags: linear-algebra, invariant-subspace

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field and let $V$ be a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space.

Let $\phi,\psi:V\rightarrow V$ be linear maps, such that $\phi\circ\psi=\psi\circ\phi$.

I have shown using induction that if $U\leq_{\phi}V$ (i.e. it $U$ is a subspace and $\phi$-invariant), then $U\leq_{\phi^k}V$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

Now I want to show that if $\phi$ is invertible and if $U\leq_{\phi}V$, then $U\leq_{\phi^z}V$ for all $z\in \mathbb{Z}$.

For that we have to take cases, if $z\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ then we would get the previous case and if $z\in \mathbb{Z}_{<0}$ we use the inverse linear map of $\phi$ and then we get the previous result.

My idea is the following:

If $z=:n\in \mathbb{Z}_{> 0}$, so $z=n\in \mathbb{N}$, the from the previous result it follows that $U$ $\ \phi^n$-invariant.

Since $\phi$ isinvertible there is a linear map $\chi$ such that $\chi:=\phi^{-1}$.

If $z=:-n\in \mathbb{Z}_{< 0}$, with $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then $\phi^{-n}=\left (\phi^{-1}\right )^n=\chi^n$.  Then if we show that $U$ is $\chi$-invariant then it follows from the previous result that $U$ is $\ \phi^{-n}$-invariant.

Is that correct?

Or do we show that in an other way?

Comment: Depends. How do you use the inverse linear map to show this?

Comment: I added my idea in the question above. @k.stm

Comment: And how would you show that $U$ is $χ$-invariant?

Comment: I thought that as follows: Since $U$ is $\phi$-invariant, we have that $\phi (u)\in U$for $u\in U$. Let $\phi (u)=:v$. Then we have that $\chi \left (\phi (u)\right )=\chi (v) \Rightarrow u=\chi (v)$ Does this help us? @k.stm

Comment: It does not. You only have shown $χφ(U) ⊆ U$, you want $χ(U) ⊆ U$. Thing is, the statement is false in general and only true if you consider finite dimensional subspaces $U ⊆ V$. Can you see why?

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't why. Could you explain that to me? @k.stm

Answer (score 1):

The result does not hold in general. First consider the level of sets: Doubling and halfing are inverse to each other on $ℚ$, so take $φ \colon ℚ → ℚ,~x ↦ 2x$ and $χ\colon ℚ → ℚ,~x ↦ \frac x 2$. Then $φ(ℤ) ⊆ ℤ$ but $χ(ℤ) \not\subseteq ℤ$.

You can carry this over by taking vector spaces generated by these sets: Let $K$ be a field. For $V = \bigoplus_{x ∈ ℚ} K$ and $U = \bigoplus_{m ∈ ℤ} K$, we have $U ⊆ V$ and since $φ$ and $χ$ are given on a basis of $V$, we can extend both of them them to $V → V$. Now $φ(U) ⊆ U$, but $χ(U) \not\subseteq U$.

The result does however hold if $U$ is finite dimensional. For this observe that if $U$ is $φ$-invariant, $φ$ can be restricted to $φ \colon U → U$. Now $φ$ is injective because it’s the restriction of an invertible map. What can you conclude? How does this relate to $χ$?

Comment: If $\phi$ is invertible does it have to be bijective?

Comment: Or is my idea for the proof that $U$ is $\phi^z$-invariant completely wrong?

Comment: Invertible maps are bijective, yes. If $U$ is $ϕ$-invariant, then it is $ϕ^z$-invariant for $z ∈ ℕ_0$. But $U$ does not need to be $ϕ^{-1}$-invariant in general, see my examples. However, if $U$ is finite-dimensional, it is indeed $ϕ^{-1}$-invariant, nonetheless. But this requires an extra argument, exploiting the finite dimensionality of $U$. Think about this.

Comment: What we are not given that condition, are we?

Comment: So do we have to show the desired result using an other way?

Comment: @MaryStar Think about it – maybe ask a separate question if you really cannot make any progress. I’m done here.